# java jface triggering event when return/ enter is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jface, key-events

Thanks for any and all previous help that was given.

What I'm trying to do is when the enter button is pressed that an event is triggered.
Here is the code that I have written

```
    txtGolfName = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    txtGolfName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        for(int index = 0; index < gcName.length(); index++)
            if((txtGolfName.getText()).charAt(index) == '\r')
                System.out.println("Success");
            else
                System.out.println("Not Yet");
        }
    });
    txtGolfName.setBounds(180, 90, 300, 25);
```

Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `keyCode` of the event:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR)
            System.out.println("Success");
        else
            System.out.println("Not Yet");
    }
}
```